# Microsoft Windows Advertising SDK in apps or software deployed outside of Windows App Store

Tags: java, c++, windows, java-native-interface, windows-store-apps

Is it possible to use Microsoft Windows Advertising SDK to put Ads banners in an app or software that you do not deploy/upload to the Microsoft App Store?

Say that you have some Windows XP, Windows Vista, Windows 7 etc software that is either in C/C++ or JAVA and you want to add Microsoft Advertising SDK to it.

What about adding it to web apps or apps done with some cross platform like NativeScript or React Native or other?

So is it possible to use Microsoft Windows Advertising SDK for apps that you do NOT upload to Microsoft Windows App STORE, ie deploying from your own website...

Answer (score 0):

> So is it possible to use Microsoft Windows Advertising SDK for apps
>   that you do NOT upload to Microsoft Windows App STORE, ie deploying
>   from your own website...

Currently, you're not able to do that. Because the live Ad Unit starts serving in 24 hours after your app gets published successfully.

For web apps, you can only add it to the host web app which can be uploaded to Store as UWP app.

Comment: Thanks I'd like to accept your answer but I need some info as to if its "allowed" not just if its possible/impossible technically. For example, someone I guess COULD deploy a version of APP on App Store and then use the same Ad Unit ID inside another Windows7 version of app that is not published on Store but is deployed from your own website. So would be GREAT if you can link to official Microsoft policies on Ads etc.